# cordova platform add android get an error in JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, android, cordova

I just install my cordova 3.3 in my windows 8, when i use the command "cordova platform add android" i receive this error message

```
Error: failed to run 'java -version', make sure your java environment is set up including jdk and jre
your JAVA_HOME variable is c:\program files(x86)\java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin
Error: Command failed: 'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

here's my system variable for JAVA_HOME
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin
and for the path, i added this one
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7
anyone can help me with this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot saved the day!

Answer (score 0):

Set your JAVA_HOME to c:\program files(x86)\java\jdk1.7.0_25