# Phonegap Cordova build android Error

Tags: java, android, cordova, ant, phonegap-build

Hi guys I'm trying build my first phonegap App, and i've set up the eclispe, phonegap and jdk on my Windows 64bit os. However when i run the `$cordova build android` I'm getting the following details with the BUILD ERROR like bellow.

> Running command:
>   C:\Users\vishwant\phonegap\hi\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat
>   Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jre8\lib\tools.jar Buildfile:
>   C:\Users\vishwant\phonegap\hi\platforms\android\build.xml
>
> -set-mode-check:
>
> -set-debug-files:
>
> -check-env:  [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 23.0.2  [checkenv] Installed at C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk
>
> -setup:
>        [echo] Project Name: HiVishwa   [gettype] Project Type: Application
>
> -set-debug-mode:
>
> -debug-obfuscation-check:
>
> -pre-build:
>
> -build-setup: [getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 20.0.0
>        [echo] Resolving Build Target for HiVishwa... [gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.4.2 [gettarget] API level:        19
>        [echo] ----------
>        [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
>        [echo] ----------
>        [echo] Resolving Dependencies for HiVishwa... [dependency] Library dependencies: [dependency] [dependency] ------------------
>
> ### [dependency] Ordered libraries: [dependency] [dependency]
>
> ```
>  [echo] ----------
>  [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...
> ```
>
> nodeps:
>
> -set-mode-check:
>
> -set-debug-files:
>
> -check-env:  [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 23.0.2  [checkenv] Installed at C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk
>
> -setup:
>        [echo] Project Name: CordovaLib   [gettype] Project Type: Android Library
>
> -set-debug-mode:
>
> -debug-obfuscation-check:
>
> -pre-build:
>
> -build-setup: [getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 20.0.0
>        [echo] Resolving Build Target for CordovaLib... [gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.4.2 [gettarget] API level:        19
>        [echo] ----------
>        [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
>       [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\vishwant\phonegap\hi\platforms\android\CordovaLib\ant-build\rsObj
>       [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\vishwant\phonegap\hi\platforms\android\CordovaLib\ant-build\rsLibs
>        [echo] ----------
>        [echo] Resolving Dependencies for CordovaLib... [dependency] Library dependencies: [dependency] No Libraries [dependency]
>   [dependency] ------------------
>
> -code-gen: [mergemanifest] Found Deleted Target File [mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one. [mergemanifest] Manifest
>   merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
>        [echo] Handling aidl files...
>        [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
>        [echo] ----------
>        [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
>        [echo] ----------
>        [echo] Handling Resources...
>        [aapt] Found new input file
>        [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
>        [echo] ----------
>        [echo] Handling BuildConfig class... [buildconfig] Generating BuildConfig class.
>
> -pre-compile:
>
> -compile:
>
> **BUILD FAILED
>   C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:601: The
>   following error occurred while executing this line:
>   C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:720: The
>   following error occurred while executing this line:
>   C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:734:
>   Unable to find a javac compiler; com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on
>   the classpath. Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK. It is
>   currently set to "C:\Program Files\Java\jre8"**
>
> Total time: 6 seconds Error code 1 for command: cmd with args:
>   /s,/c,ant,debug,-f,C:\Users\vishwant\phonegap\hi\platforms\android\build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolu
>   te.dir=ant-gen Error:
>   C:\Users\vishwant\phonegap\hi\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat:
>   Command failed with exit code 2
>       at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\vishwant\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:135:23)
>       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
>       at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)

Environment variables
1.User variables

```
%ANT_HOME% C:\Program Files (x86)\WinAnt
JAVA_HOME% C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\bin
```

2.System Variables

```
 %Path% -----> C:\Program Files (x86)\RSA SecurID Token Common;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;%systemroot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\platform-tools\;C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\tools\;C:\Users\vishwant\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ant\ant\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\WinAnt\bin\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\WinAnt\bin\

ANDROID_HOME% C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\tools\
```

I appreciate if anyone correct me, where i'm going wrong. I tried for two days!!

Thanks.

Comment: The error clearly says that the JAVA_HOME is not properly defined. The error say it is defined as `C:\Program Files\Java\jre8` where as it should have been defined as `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11`. Open up a command prompt window and type `echo %JAVA_HOME%` to check the value set.

Comment: set up the PATH correctly. You should follow this link http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html

Comment: thanks for the reply @frank. Yeah error says its not set to jdk. But the value of the command `echo %JAVA_HOME%` is **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11**

Comment: @Vishwa have a look over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21743873/cordova-platform-add-android-get-an-error-in-java-home) for setting your JAVA_HOME

Comment: @frank Thanka alot. After I restarted my comp it's working fine!! Kudos.