# VS2013 Cordova apps Exit code 1

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

I am working on a cordova app using VS2013 tools for cordova and typescript.

I recently updated node and then i started getting this error

```
Building platform: android (TaskId:22)
1>  Debug (TaskId:22)
1>  ------ Build configuration options: --debug (TaskId:22)
1>  Running command: E:\Apps\myapp\myapp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat --debug   (TaskId:22)
1>  E:\Apps\myapp\myapp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126 (TaskId:22)
1>                      throw e; (TaskId:22)
1>                            ^ (TaskId:22)
1>  TypeError: Cannot read property 'prepEnv' of undefined (TaskId:22)
1>      at Object.module.exports.run (E:\Apps\myapp\myapp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\cordova\lib\build.js:326:19) (TaskId:22)
1>      at E:\Apps\myapp\myapp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\cordova\build:36:22 (TaskId:22)
1>      at _fulfilled (E:\Apps\myapp\myapp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:798:54) (TaskId:22)
1>      at self.promiseDispatch.done (E:\Apps\myapp\myapp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:827:30) (TaskId:22)
1>      at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (E:\Apps\myapp\myapp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:760:13) (TaskId:22)
1>      at E:\Apps\myapp\myapp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:574:44 (TaskId:22)
1>      at flush (E:\Apps\myapp\myapp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:108:17) (TaskId:22)
1>      at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11) (TaskId:22)
1>  Command finished with error code 1: E:\Apps\myapp\myapp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat --debug,, (TaskId:22)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a known issue, adding a space to the project's path fixes it:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1192337/tools-for-apache-cordova-ctp-3-1-cant-build-for-android

Note this happens only when targeting Android on CTP3.1.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I remove node.js and reinstalled it. And I had to set my  system variable for JAVA_HOME and JAVA like in this answer [cordova platform add android get an error in JAVA_HOME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21743873/cordova-platform-add-android-get-an-error-in-java-home) (without (x86) despite it is in C:\Program Files (x86)).

Answer (score 0):

I have exact same error but in 2015 CTP 6. I have correct JAVA_HOME. 
Here is my env.

- angularjs 1.3.14
- jQuery 1.8.0
- JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40
- ADT_HOME =
  C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk
- ANT_HOME =C:\apache-ant-1.9.4-bin\apache-ant-1.9.4
- Node.js verion 0.12.2

Everything works fine in Android and Ripple. I get this error while compiling for device. Device is connected.

....\bld\Debug\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126 (TaskId:11)

```
                throw e; (TaskId:11)
                       ^ (TaskId:11)
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'prepEnv' of undefined (TaskId:11)

```
  at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11) (TaskId:11)
```